# HTML/CSS: IE8 background overflowing border

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

In IE8 one of my buttons background's is overflowing it's border. Here is an image that highlights the problem:

[image: stupid IE8]

A live example can be seen here: http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/

The markup for the button is:

```
<a class="button alpha bold" href="#">
   <img alt="rcn icon" src="http://rcnhca.org.uk/sites/first_steps/wp-content/themes/megaamazing/library/images/rcn-icon.png">
</a>
```

And the css (I use filters to draw a gradient instead of an image):

```
a.button.alpha, a.button.alpha:focus {
    margin-left: 0px;
}

a.button.omega, a.button.omega:focus {
    margin-right: 0px;
}

a.button{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 5px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 2.438em;
    line-height: 2.438em;
    padding: 0 0.938em;
    border: #3a90a7 2px solid;
    font-size: 0.938em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #202d32;
    background: #ffffff;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #e5e5e5 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#e5e5e5));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e5e5e5',GradientType=0 );
    border-radius: 5px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.oldie a.button{
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#e5e5e5',GradientType=0 );
}

a.button:hover {
    border: #202d32 solid 2px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 0 3px #FFFFFF inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0 0 3px #FFFFFF inset;
}

a.button:active{
    padding-top: 0.125em;
    padding-left: 1.063em;
    padding-right: 0.813em;
    height: 2.313em;
    background: #e5e5e5; /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: #cccccc;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #cccccc 0%, #cccccc 3%, #e5e5e5 5%, #ffffff 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#cccccc), color-stop(3%,#cccccc), color-stop(5%,#e5e5e5), color-stop(100%,#ffffff));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #cccccc 0%,#cccccc 3%,#e5e5e5 5%,#ffffff 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #cccccc 0%,#cccccc 3%,#e5e5e5 5%,#ffffff 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #cccccc 0%,#cccccc 3%,#e5e5e5 5%,#ffffff 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #cccccc 0%,#cccccc 3%,#e5e5e5 5%,#ffffff 100%);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #AAAAAA inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #AAAAAA inset; 
}

.oldie a.button:active {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e5e5e5', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 );
}

a.button img {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 15px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Does anyone know what's going on? Thanks.

Comment: can't reproduce on IE8, Win XP. BTW you shouldn't declare `0px` as property values on the CSS, as the 0 measurement has no unit. specify `0` instead.

Comment: I can, I presume it's the 1px white space to the right of "Join the RCN"

Comment: @Rob2211 that's the one.

Comment: It looks fine to me in IE8. However, in IE9 both of those buttons are messed up on all four corners. You need to make sure filter is only used in browsers lower than IE9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't explain why, but when you remove the horizontal margins on the anchor it fixes the problem (both left and right)

My best guess is that the IE filter is doing something unpredictable.

If you wrap the element then apply a margin to that instead, it should solve it.

Comment: Thanks, I also found by changing the padding values to px instead of ems it fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to do this for IE8 because its not support css3 BTW its work in IE9.

for more details about IE & CSS compatibility check this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I am using filters which IE8 supports. The CSS3 is progressive enhancement for cool browsers.

Comment: thanks jaiff I used pie but it was slowing down my page a lot.

Comment: try this add `-pie-poll: false;` to all the elements on the page that had PIE applied to them then see what happen.

Comment: To complement Jaiff's comment it's worth nothing that `-pie-poll` is disabled by default on IE7 and lower, so any performance increases gained by that setting would only be seen on IE8/9

Comment: That improved it a bit, however I get lots of bugs with PIE on.